# An easy way to display a message box to the user in D

Tags: linux, d

I plan to start using D to do simple OS scripting on Ubuntu Linux (using scriptlike library).

I'd like to write a script, that pop-ups a modal message box (with two buttons labelled: "yes" and "no") that return user's choice.

I don't care about efficiency; I would like API to similar to VBA's `MsgBox` function, so I don't have to design a full-blown UI with message queue just to get Yes or No from the user.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't find a native D solution, I can use `zenity` (assuming it is installed on user's machine):

```
import scriptlike;

void main()
{
    auto choice = tryRun("zenity --question --text 'Do you want to start backup?'");
    writeln("User choice ", choice==1?"No":"Yes");
}
```

Comment: If you're comfortable shelling out to zenity, you might consider `xmessage` as well -- it's not gtk-based so it might be more widespread.  On the other hand, it also looks pretty old-fashioned.

Comment: You could use GtkD (https://github.com/gtkd-developers/GtkD) and call GtkMessageDialog() (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMessageDialog.html).